# QListWidget not removing items on screen

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

Im using QListWidget to show names as a type of dropdown when someone
types entries in another QLineEdit field.  It hits the database and shows
all possibilities to choose from.  As they type, the list changes, so I want
it to delete all entries and re-fill the QListWidget.

When I call the following code, it indeed empties the QListWidget list, but
the screen elements are still visible.  Can someone help me figure out why
they arent being removed from the display?  Im using Qt 4.8.4.  Thank you!

```
void myClass::clearListWidget()
{
    QListWidget * lw = m_ui->db_listWidget;

    while(lw->selectedItems().size())
    {
         delete lw->takeItem(0);
    }
    lw->update();
    lw->repaint();
    qApp->processEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use slot void QListWidget::clear() to clear all contents. QListWidget documentation is [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html).